# Store array in Mongodb collection through Mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, csv, express, mongoose

I'm very new to Mongoose and ran into some issues trying to import a practice Kaggle csv file into a Mongodb database. The csv file is https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata.

I'm looking to store the values given as an array string as an array object, but couldn't do so. All entries show up as strings in the database.

I'm using Express and Mongoose. I used csv-parser to parse the file and tried to manually convert some data fields into js objects, but this doesn't stop the string conversion and gives errors.

Here is the code I used to parse and to create the database:

```
fs.createReadStream('./../archive/movies.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function(csvrow) {
        data.push(csvrow);
    }).on('end', async function() {
        console.log('Data process finished');
        // console.log(data)
        try {
            await Movie.create(data);
            console.log('Database creation complete');
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
```

Here is a part of my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    budget: {
        type: Number,
        require: [true, 'Must have budget']
    },
    genres: {
        type: Array,
        require: [true, 'Must have genres']
    },
    homepage: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, 'Must have homepage']
    },
    ...
```

I encountered this issue when I was trying to find() a movie that belongs to a certain genre. What should I do to make sure that the values stay as arrays in the database?

I've tried changing the type to object, and to do {type:{type:...}}.

Thank you for reading my question!

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved by using ref and populate()
[here](https://bezkoder.com/mongoose-one-to-many-relationship/) is the complete example/tutorial